# Ansible - Append variable for same precedence

Tags: append, ansible, operator-precedence

I'd like to append my variable for a `set_fact` in the same precedence. See this link: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable

The naming of the variable has to be the same in both yml files.

In `group_vars/all.yml` I have defined:

```
my_var: 
  - value
  - another
```

And in `group_vars/hostgroup.yml` I have defined

```
my_var: 
  - win
```

What I expect `my_var` is:

```
{{ value }}{{ another }}{{ win }}
```

What it actually is:

```
{{ win }}
```

How do I ensure my `set_fact` appends both variables.

Comment: Which part of the linked page refers to appending to a variable? I think because both variables are set as `group_vars` (on the same priority level) the later (more specific `hostgroup.yml`) simply wins.

Comment: Edited the link.
But how do I append them, while they have the same naming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to merge lists with default inventory plugins.

Your only option is to merge them in runtime with `set_fact`:

```
- set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ my_var + ['win'] }}"
```

Comment: That kinda sucks. There is absolutely no way? Damn.

Comment: Nope, merge behaviour is there only for dicts, not lists. You can always write your own inventory scripts or var plugins to overcome this.

Comment: Oke. Thanks for the reply. Can't give +1. But it's listed.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov as of 2022, is there still no way to "extend" a previously defined variable? For instance, if `my_list` is defined with 2 elements in `goup_vars`, having a way to extend its value in `host_vars`? with a variable `&var` maybe?